# Cognos 10- enabling secondary Y2 axis in chart

Tags: charts, cognos-10

I am trying to enable the second y-axis in the cognos(report studio) line chart.But unable to find an option to set that y2 axis property to "yes". Can anyone please help me to find the way to enable it. And please guide where to find axis assignment property also ...I have attached my chart properties here!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Combination chart. The chart property 'Axes->Y2 Axis' should be set to 'Show'. You can add multiple entries into the Series section of the chart; once added, you can select each series in turn and set the Series properties 'General->Chart Type' to 'Line', and 'General->Axis Assignment' to 'Y1 Axis' or 'Y2 Axis' as appropriate. This is valid for Cognos 10.1 Report Studio, other release versions may differ.